# Upgrade Request Required when running exec in Kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

Im using fabric8 Kubernetes Java Client and Im accessing Kubernetes through HTTP, I followed the example from 
[fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/ExecExample.java) but I get the following error:

```
Expected HTTP 100 but received 400 instead, Bad Request.
```

What do I need to do to upgrade my connection to http/2?

Comment: That looks like the Kubernetes API server didn't like something about your request. Do you have any more details on the HTTP 400 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this has to do with http2, because Kubernetes exec uses SPDY, the problem went away when I upgraded to curl version > 7.36 and installed nghttp2 on the server.

After installing curl I was able to get the response by adding some headers

`curl -H "Connection: upgrade" -H "Upgrade: SPDY/3.1" {master url:port/pod/exec}`

Comment: Hi, I'm not having any luck with these headers , `curl -H "Connection: upgrade" -H "Upgrade: SPDY/3.1" http://172.10.2.4:8080/api/v1/namespaces/mailho/pods/webmail-2495503454-zufoc/exec?container=webmail&command=ls
[2] 28991
` . The response I get `[2] 28991`

Comment: Your shell is backgrounding the process when it sees `&`. You need to wrap the whole URL in quotes to avoid evaluating special characters - `curl -H "Connection: upgrade" -H "Upgrade: SPDY/3.1" "http://172.10.2.4:8080/api/v1/namespaces/mailho/pods/webmail‌​-2495503454-zufoc/ex‌​ec?container=webmail‌​&command=ls"`