# Kubernetes pod exec API - Upgrade request required

Tags: kubernetes, postman

I am trying to get the POST and GET requests working (via Postman) but this is what I'm getting,

**GET Request**

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mypod/exec
```

**GET Response**

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 404
}
```

**POST Request**

```
curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mypod/exec?command=ls&container=my-container&stderr=true&stdout=true'
```

**POST Response**

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Upgrade request required",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
}
```

Any idea on how to get these requests working? What parameters need to be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are trying to exec into a pod. A websocket connection is required if you want to exec into a pod.

For a websocket connection, an http(s) call is made first, followed by an upgrade request to websocket using the *HTTP Upgrade* header.

curl does not support upgrade from http to websocket. Hence the error.

*[kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) exec* would be handy for this use case.

You can also try other cli tools which support websockets, like

- [wscat](https://github.com/websockets/wscat)

Comment: Yes, it was not possible via curl, so we used _kubectl_ instead.

Comment: This person claims they were able to get it working with curl: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/409#issuecomment-1241425302

Comment: Oh, found a second person that claims to have gotten `curl` to work with `exec`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37396806

Comment: For reference, I eventually found out how to implement the https->websocket upgrade in Rust code: https://github.com/debate-map/app/blob/c2f62f7aabc603abf3f4c23c8357f1323537137d/Packages/rust-shared/src/utils/k8s/k8s_client.rs#L14

Answer (score 2):

```
wscat -n --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"   -c 'https://200.200.200.160:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/mysql/exec?command=bash&container=mysql&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true'
```

wscat: https://github.com/websockets/wscat

[image]

Answer (score 0):

below code will work

```
from kubernetes import client, config, utils
from kubernetes.stream import stream


def execute_command_in_pod(namespace, pod_name, command):
# Load Kubernetes configuration from default location
config.load_kube_config()

# Create an instance of the Kubernetes API client
api_instance = client.CoreV1Api()

# Specify the container name if there are multiple containers in the pod
container_name = None

# Construct the command payload
exec_command = [
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    command
]

# Execute the command in the pod
try:
    response = stream(api_instance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
        pod_name,
        namespace,
        command=exec_command,
        stderr=True,
        stdin=False,
        stdout=True,
        tty=False
    )
    print("Command executed successfully. Output:")
    print(response.output)
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error executing command: {e}")
    return False
```

it from kubernetes python [git](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**