# Read/Copy files between pods via kubernetes API or using ruby client (kubeclient package) - 400 BAD Request Error

Tags: ruby, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am using ruby kubeclient library and Kubernetes APIs to read file contents from different pod from the current pod. I have set up RBAC and am able to authenticate my Kubernetes API. Followed [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/access-api-from-pod/).

*To read the file from the pod from the host I was able to try the below options:*

1. using `kubectl exec` with `cat` command to get file contents (able to see file contents on console)
2. using `kubectl cp` to copy the file from container to host (able to copy the file in the host)

I want to replicate either of these options to automate this process to run from within the container.

From the container when I run:

```
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET "https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/mypod"
```

I am able to get the details of my pod.

But when I tried the above URL with `exec` I am getting 400 Bad request errors.

```
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET "https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/mypod/exec?command=ls"
or
curl --cacert ${CACERT} --header "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -X GET "https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/mynamespace/pods/mypod/exec?command=cat&command=/tmp/myfile.txt"
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  {
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "Upgrade request required",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
```

NOTE: I found StackOverflow thread for this above error: [Kubernetes pod exec API - Upgrade request required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49250370/kubernetes-pod-exec-api-upgrade-request-required)

The recommendation was to use the CLI tool which supports WebSockets (like wscat or wssh).

I tired replacing curl with ruby rest client:

```
RestClient::Request.execute( :url => url, :method => :get, :verify_ssl => true, :ssl_ca_file => "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt", :payload => {}.to_json,
    :headers =>  {:Authorization => "Bearer %s" % [access_token]})
```

But I am getting the same 400 error.

My rbac configuration:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}.{{ .Release.Namespace}}
rules:
  - apiGroups: [ "" ]
    resources: [ "services", "pods"]
    verbs: [ "get", "list" , "watch"]
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods/exec"]
    verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
```

Is there any equivalent for `kubectl exec` or `kubectl cp` which I can use via KUBERNETES API? Or is there any sample code that shows how to use kubeclient (ruby client) to copy files in and out of containers?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_exec.py

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor no I could not found the resolution/workaround for this.

Comment: @AkhileshJoshi have you considered using a sidecar/init container to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `kubectl exec` and `kubectl cp` by design should be used for debugging/troubleshooting/testing scenarios however you can use it in an init or sidecar container (for debugging/troubleshooting/testing).
In production environment you should avoid giving access to pod/exec resource to your workload.

To achieve your goal I would recommend to use one of those methods:

1. An external storage bucket such as [Google Cloud storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#buckets).
2. A Persistent Volume with fitting access modes from one of the providers mentioned in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

If you are interested in copying files from your host machine in Kubernetes you can also find [hostPath volume concept](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) however this is not recommended way.

Warning:

> HostPath volumes present many security risks, and it is a best
> practice to avoid the use of HostPaths when possible. When a HostPath
> volume must be used, it should be scoped to only the required file or
> directory, and mounted as ReadOnly